# I have 3 issues from migrating to null-safety

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

I migrated to null-safety today and I have 3 issues that I don't know how to fix. Below, I have provided the errors and the code that each error refers to. I do not know how to fix these issues and they are the only errors left.

```
error • The body might complete normally, causing 'null' to be returned, but the return type is a potentially non-nullable type at lib\Services\firestore_service.dart:29:16 • (body_might_complete_normally)

Future<Void> saveNewAgency(Agency agency) async {
    await _db.collection('agency').doc(globals.agencyId).set(agency.toMap());
  }

      error • The property 'docs' can't be unconditionally accessed because the receiver can be 'null' at lib\screens\agent_dash_board.dart:57:43 •(unchecked_use_of_nullable_value)
I fixed similar errors to this one with the code at itemCount: (snapshot.data! as QuerySnapshot).docs.length,  in the code snippet. 
    
    return new ListView.builder(
                          itemCount: (snapshot.data! as QuerySnapshot).docs.length,
                          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                            Trxns trxns = Trxns.fromFirestore(
                                snapshot.data.docs[index].data());

  error • The body might complete normally, causing 'null' to be returned, but the return type is a potentially non-nullable type at lib\screens\appointment_calendar.dart:434:31 • (body_might_complete_normally)

Map<DateTime, List<Event?>> convertToMap(List<Event> item) {
    Map<DateTime, List>? result;

    for (int i = 0; i < item.length; i++) {
      Event data = item[i];
      //get the date and convert it to a DateTime variable
      //DateTime currentDate = DateFormat('MM-dd-yyyy - kk:mm').format(data.eventDate);
      DateTime currentDate = DateTime(data.eventDate!.year, data.eventDate!.month, data.eventDate!.day, data.eventDate!.hour, data.eventDate!.minute);

      List eventNames = [];
      //add the event name to the the eventNames list for the current date.
      //search for another event with the same date and populate the eventNames List.
      for (int j = 0; j < item.length; j++) {
        //create temp calendarItemData object.
        Event temp = item[j];
        //establish that the temp date is equal to the current date
        if (data.eventDate == temp.eventDate) {
          //add the event name to the event List.
          eventNames.add(temp.eventName);
        } //else continue
      }

      //add the date and the event to the map if the date is not contained in the map
      if (result == null) {
        result = {
          currentDate: eventNames
        };
      } else {
        result[currentDate] = eventNames;
      }
      return result as Map<DateTime, List<Event?>>;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dart
Future<Void> saveNewAgency(Agency agency) async {
  await _db.collection('agency').doc(globals.agencyId).set(agency.toMap());
}
```

Try returning `Future<void>` I'm not sure where you are getting `Void` with a capital V from.

---

```dart
    return new ListView.builder(
                          itemCount: (snapshot.data! as QuerySnapshot).docs.length,
                          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                            Trxns trxns = Trxns.fromFirestore(
                                snapshot.data.docs[index].data());
```

The solution as discussed below was to do this:

```dart
Trxns trxns = Trxns.fromFirestore((snapshot.data! as QuerySnapshot).docs[index]!.data() as Map<String, dynamic>);
```

---

```dart
Map<DateTime, List<Event?>> convertToMap(List<Event> item) {
    Map<DateTime, List>? result;

    for (int i = 0; i < item.length; i++) {
      Event data = item[i];
      //get the date and convert it to a DateTime variable
      //DateTime currentDate = DateFormat('MM-dd-yyyy - kk:mm').format(data.eventDate);
      DateTime currentDate = DateTime(data.eventDate!.year, data.eventDate!.month, data.eventDate!.day, data.eventDate!.hour, data.eventDate!.minute);

      List eventNames = [];
      //add the event name to the the eventNames list for the current date.
      //search for another event with the same date and populate the eventNames List.
      for (int j = 0; j < item.length; j++) {
        //create temp calendarItemData object.
        Event temp = item[j];
        //establish that the temp date is equal to the current date
        if (data.eventDate == temp.eventDate) {
          //add the event name to the event List.
          eventNames.add(temp.eventName);
        } //else continue
      }

      //add the date and the event to the map if the date is not contained in the map
      if (result == null) {
        result = {
          currentDate: eventNames
        };
      } else {
        result[currentDate] = eventNames;
      }
      return result as Map<DateTime, List<Event?>>;
    }
  }
```

I think you meant to put that return statement after the for loop, not inside of it.

Comment: thank you for your help. The first and third fixes worked but the second on did not work. I made the changes you suggested and get this error:    The getter 'docs' isn't defined for the type 'Object' at lib\screens\agent_dash_board.dart:57:44 .    Here is the code now:  Trxns? trxns = Trxns.fromFirestore(
                            snapshot.data?.docs[index].data());

Comment: Can you add more context to the code surrounding the second problem? Perhaps you could try `Trxns trxns = Trxns.fromFirestore( (snapshot.data! as QuerySnapshot).docs[index].data());` since it is consistent with with the approach you took for the `itemCount` argument.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and got this error:   The argument type 'Object?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<String, dynamic>' .   Here is the Trxn.fromFirestore() code snippet,   Trxns.fromFirestore(Map<String, dynamic> firestore)
      : trxnId = firestore['trxnId'],
        agentId = firestore['agentId'];

Comment: is `.data()` meant to return a `Map<String, dynamic>` ? It appears the `fromFirestore` method expects you to pass a `Map<String, dynamic>`. Maybe you can cast it to one? like: `Trxns trxns = Trxns.fromFirestore( (snapshot.data! as QuerySnapshot).docs[index]!.data() as Map<String, dynamic>);`